# sql query - how to avoid "virtually" duplicate records depending on time

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do a sql query that will return all the records in a table except for those that have less than 2 seconds difference to another record?

Example - Consider these 5 records:

```
16:24:00
16:24:10
16:24:11
16:24:12
16:24:30
```

The query should return:

```
16:24:00
16:24:10
16:24:30
```

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: By the description the `16:24:10` would not be included because it is only 1 second different from another record.  Is the difference only considered for those with time values less than a particular record?

Comment: @MarkWilkins ideally all the records should be considered, I mean, there is no comparison with a particular record but with all of them... and yes, you are right, I have edited the question in order to include 16:24:10

Answer (score 1):

best solution - number and sort your timestamps, self join on condition of 3 seconds or more only on consecutive records:

```
select a.* from (
     select timestamp, 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
    from table
    JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
    order by timestamp

 )a inner join (

    select timestamp, 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
   from table
    JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
    order by timestamp

 )b on time_to_sec(a.timestamp)<time_to_sec(b.timestamp)-2 and
 a.row_number=b.row_number-1
```

to get no more than one per 3 seconds, break it into 3sec intervals and group by that, take the lowest existing value(if it exists) with min()

```
select min(timestamp)
from table
group by concat(left(timestamp, 6),3*round(right(timestamp, 2)/3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago.

Here is what I came up with and which works quite nice.

---

I. This query will group all results from 'your_table' (here referred as x), by 5 seconds.
This means it will output the count of results that are inside a 5 second timeframe.

> ```
> SELECT count(x.id), x.created_at FROM your_table AS x 
>        GROUP BY ( 60 * 60 * HOUR( x.created_at ) + 
>                   60 * FLOOR( MINUTE( x.created_at )) +
>                   FLOOR( SECOND( x.created_at ) / 5))
> ```

II. This query will group all results from 'your_table' (here referred as x), by 1 minute.
Like above it will output the count of results that are inside a 1 minute timeframe.

> ```
> SELECT count(x.id), x.created_at FROM your_table AS x 
>        GROUP BY ( 60 * HOUR( x.created_at ) + 
>                   FLOOR( MINUTE( x.created_at ) / 1))
> ```

Example output for query I and your input.

```
count(x.id), created_at 
1 16:24:00  
3 16:24:10  
1 16:24:30
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although I had already marked this answer as accepted I have now realised that the first query will return records where created_at has seconds ending with either 0 or 5 (obviously because of the division applied). Only in cases where such records do not exist it will return a different value for the second of created_at. Therefore, there may be duplicates with created_at with seconds not ending with 0 or 5 that wouldn't be taken into account, i.e. from 53 to 55 should be considered as 1, but this query would return 2 which is from 50 to 55 and 55 to 00. What do you think? Very clever btw